# Reading dynamic XML nodes in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, database, dynamic

I have the following XML structure:

```
set @MailXML =
'<MailingCompany>
    <Mailman>
        <Name>Jamie</Name>
            <Age> 24 </Age>
            <Letter>
            <DestinationAddress> 440 Mountain View Parade </DestinationAddress>
            <DestinationCountry> USA </DestinationCountry>
                <OriginCountry> Australia </OriginCountry>
            <OriginAddress> 120 St Kilda Road </OriginAddress>
            </Letter>
    </Mailman>
</MailingCompany>'
```

My SQL currently looks like this:

```
-- Mail Insertion
INSERT INTO mailDB.dbo.Mailman
   SELECT
       m.value('Name[1]','varchar(50)') as Name,
       m.value('Age[1]','varchar(50)') as Age
   FROM 
       @MailXML.nodes('/MailingCompany/Mailman') as A(m)

SET @MailPersonFK = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

-- Letter Insertion
INSERT INTO mailDB.dbo.Letter
    SELECT 
        l.value('DestinationAddress[1]', 'varchar(50)') as DestinationAddress,
        l.value('DestinationCountry[1]', 'varchar(50)') as DestinationCountry,
        l.value('OriginCountry[1]', 'varchar(50)') as OriginCountry,
        l.value('OriginAddress[1]', 'varchar(50)') as OriginAddress
        @MailPersonFK as MailID
    FROM  
        @MailXML.nodes('MailingCompany/Mailman/Letter') as B(l)
```

I am trying to extract the `Mailman` and Letter data into their own respective tables. I have got that working however my issue is that the `MailCompany` node is dynamic. Sometimes it may be `MailVehicle`, for example, and I still need
to read the corresponding `Mailman` and `Letter` node data and insert them into their own respective tables.

So both

```
FROM @MailXML.nodes('/MailingCompany/Mailman') as A(t)
```

and

```
FROM @MailXML.nodes('MailingCompany/Mailman/Letter') as B(l)
```

Will need to be changed to allow `MailingCompany` to be dynamic.

I have tried to extract the parent node and concatenate it into a string to put into the .nodes function like the following:

```
set @DynXML = '/' + @parentNodeVar + '/Mailman'

FROM @MailXML.nodes(@DynXML) as A(t)
```

However I get the following error:

> The argument 1 of the XML data type method "nodes" must be a string literal.

How can I overcome this dynamic XML issue?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: as per my understanding , you trying to say that Mailman and Letter is never changes but parent node of Mailman  may be change . so you have difficulty to get data of Mailman and Letter .means you want to find Mailman  and Letter node dynamically from xml .Am iI Right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this reduced example:

```
DECLARE @xml1 XML=
N'<MailingCompany>
  <Mailman>
    <Name>Jamie</Name>
    <Letter>
      <DestinationAddress> 440 Mountain View Parade </DestinationAddress>
    </Letter>
  </Mailman>
</MailingCompany>';

DECLARE @xml2 XML=
N'<OtherName>
  <Mailman>
    <Name>Jodie</Name>
    <Letter>
      <DestinationAddress> This is the other address </DestinationAddress>
    </Letter>
  </Mailman>
</OtherName>';

SELECT @xml1.value(N'(*/Mailman/Name)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Mailman_Name
      ,@xml1.value(N'(*/Mailman/Letter/DestinationAddress)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS DestinationAddress
SELECT @xml2.value(N'(*/Mailman/Name)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Mailman_Name
      ,@xml2.value(N'(*/Mailman/Letter/DestinationAddress)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS DestinationAddress
```

You can replace a node's name with `*`.

Another trick is the *deep search* with `//` (same result as before):

```
SELECT @xml1.value(N'(//Name)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Mailman_Name
      ,@xml1.value(N'(//DestinationAddress)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS DestinationAddress
SELECT @xml2.value(N'(//Name)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Mailman_Name
      ,@xml2.value(N'(//DestinationAddress)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS DestinationAddress
```

The general rule: Be as specific as possible.

Comment: Awesome that's exactly what I wanted. Thank you @Shnugo!

Comment: I have the exact same problem but i need to select also the "OtherName"... how can i do this? Thanks @Shnugo